# How to update value in Service from activity

Tags: android, service

I have a service start in Activity A with

```js
private void startService() {
        Intent pushIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        pushIntent.putExtra(MyService.TYPE_SCREEN, 1);
        startService(pushIntent);
    }
```

in my Service I get data from `onStartCommand`

```js
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        typeScreen = intent.getExtras().getInt(TYPE_SCREEN);
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
```

I want when change from activity A to activity B, I will update type of screen from `1` to `2` in Service.
How I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android only create one instance of a service.

> Request that a given application service be started. The Intent can
>   either contain the complete class name of a specific service
>   implementation to start, or an abstract definition through the action
>   and other fields of the kind of service to start. If this service is
>   not already running, it will be instantiated and started (creating a
>   process for it if needed); if it is running then it remains running.

So in your case, the service is already running, then you just have to send the intent with the screen 2 extra. It will only call the onStartCommand Override method.

```
 Intent pushIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        pushIntent.putExtra(MyService.TYPE_SCREEN, 2);
        startService(pushIntent);
```

Comment: If this helped you upvote it. So that others can also use it.